# vc++ - I want to compile a program which uses mysql, please direct me

Tags: mysql, visual-c++

Hai,
 I done a server program in vc++(using visualstudio 2008). At that time it worked perfectly. But after that I uninstalled the visualstudio 2010. Now I can't open that pro file using vs2008(it is saying that it can't open the file). So I copied the header,cpp files and tried to compile , but it's not compiling. I added the libmysql.lib in properties->dependencies. And  added the include path also. But still I am getting  the following errors.

So he I am producing a stub.

```
#include <winsock.h>
#include <mysql.h>

int main()
{
MySql a;
return 0;
}
```

the errors I am getting are

```
error C2065: 'MySql' : undeclared identifier
error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'a'
error C2065: 'a' : undeclared identifier
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong. Somebody please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the case wrong for the declaration:

```
MySql a;
```

should be

```
MYSQL a;
```